# Explode a column with multiple values separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How are you?

I have a database where some lines have more than one product and they are separated by a comma, as in the example below (there are other columns, but to make it more practical I only took these three).

| id | produdct | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 47 | product1, product 2 | 12000.0 |
| 48 | product3 | 48000.0 |
| 49 | product4, product1, product2 | 28800.0 |
| 50 | product1 | 2000.0 |
| 51 | product5, product2 | 32000.0 |
| 53 | product3 | 128000.0 |
| 54 | product2 | 15000.0 |
| 55 | product4, product2, product5 | 96000.0 |

I need to separate each product, making a copy of that line for each one. I tried using some functions like explode, json_normalize, I tried creating a list of lists but nothing worked. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `str.split` and `explode`

```
df['produdct'] = df['produdct'].str.split(', ')
new_df = df.explode('produdct')

   id   produdct     value
0  47   product1   12000.0
0  47  product 2   12000.0
1  48   product3   48000.0
2  49   product4   28800.0
2  49   product1   28800.0
2  49   product2   28800.0
3  50   product1    2000.0
4  51   product5   32000.0
4  51   product2   32000.0
5  53   product3  128000.0
6  54   product2   15000.0
7  55   product4   96000.0
7  55   product2   96000.0
7  55   product5   96000.0
```

Comment: Dude, it worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: No, problem and good luck. You were on the right track just `explode` works with list-likes - i.e., lists, tuples, sets, Series and np.ndarray. You currently have strings so you just needed to convert before using `explode`.